# How to send SMS Verification code to user without using Firebase in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

**I am trying to send a **SMS verification** code to a user in my app but i cant. Can any one help me, i will be very thankful to you kindly help me to resolve this issue **

Answer (score 0):

Well since you not using API then you can either create this by using users sim card to send the verification message, I mean they would send a message like normal message but to their self, use below packages

https://pub.dev/packages/sms/

https://pub.dev/packages/otp/

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_otp/

Comment: i dnt want to send sms from same mobile i want to send message to a user when user enter a number and click on button then a verification code should be send him form a number for example 4567